# Text output from results of APDL

Tags: workbench, ansys, ansys-apdl

I need to write UY1 displacement of node1 as Text file in ANSYS APDL code given in ANSYS Verification Manual, VM17. Presently, it only gives graph plot of UY1 and I am unable to locate the text file (in case it is already there) or let me know kindly how to get values of this plot.

Thanking you in anticipation.

```
C*** USING SHELL63 ELEMENTS

ANTYPE,STATIC ! STATIC ANALYSIS

ET,1,SHELL181   !  Changed

R,1,6.350 ! SHELL THICKNESS

MP,EX,1,3102.75

MP,NUXY,1,0.3

:COM CREATE FINITE ELEMENT MODEL

R1 = 2000   !2540 ! SHELL MID-SURFACE RADIUS

L = 200     !254 ! HALF THE LENGTH

PI = 4*ATAN(1) ! VALUE OF PI COMPUTED

THETA = 0.1*180/PI ! 0.1 RADIANS CONVERTED TO DEGREES

CSYS,1 ! CYLINDRICAL CO-ORDINATE SYSTEM

N,1,R1,90 ! NODES 1 AND 2 ARE CREATED AT POINTS

N,2,R1,90,L ! A AND B RESPECTIVELY.

K,1,R1,90

K,2,R1,(90-THETA)

K,3,R1,90,L

K,4,R1,(90-THETA),L

ESIZE,,2 

! TWO DIVISION ALONG THE REGION BOUNDARY

A,1,3,4,2

AMESH,1

NUMMRG,NODE

FINISH

*CREATE,SOLVIT,MAC

/PREP7

:COM APPLY BOUNDARY CONDITIONS

NSEL,S,LOC,Z,0

DSYM,SYMM,Z

NSEL,S,LOC,Y,90

DSYM,SYMM,X

NSEL,S,LOC,Y,(90-THETA)

D,ALL,UX,,,,,UY,UZ

NSEL,ALL

FINISH

:COM SOLUTION PHASE

:COM SINCE THE SOLUTION OUTPUT IS SUBSTANTIAL IT IS DIVERTED TO A

:COM SCRATCH FILE

/OUTPUT,SCRATCH

/SOLUTION

NLGEOM,ON ! LARGE DEFLECTION TURNED ON

OUTRES,,1 ! WRITE SOLUTION ON RESULTS FILE FOR EVERY SUBSTEP

F,1,FY,-250 ! 1/4 TH OF THE TOTAL LOAD APPLIED DUE TO SYMMETRY

NSUBST,30 ! BEGIN WITH 30 SUBSTEPS

ARCLEN,ON,5 ! ARC-LENGTH SOLUTION TECHNIQUE TURNED ON WITH

! MAX. ARC-LENGTH KEPT AT 5 TO COMPUTE AND STORE

! SUFFICIENT INTERMEDIATE SOLUTION INFORMATION

SOLVE

FINISH

/OUTPUT

:COM POSTPROCESSING PHASE

/POST26

NSOL,2,1,U,Y ! STORE UY DISPLACEMENT OF NODE 1

NSOL,3,2,U,Y ! STORE UY DISPLACEMENT OF NODE 2

PROD,4,1,,,LOAD,,,4*250 ! TOTAL LOAD IS 4*250 DUE TO QUARTER SYMMETRY

PROD,5,2,,,,,,-1 ! CHANGE SIGNS OF THE DISPLACEMENT VALUES

PROD,6,3,,,,,,-1

*GET,UY1,VARI,2,EXTREM,VMIN

*GET,UY2,VARI,3,EXTREM,VMIN

PRVAR,2,3,4 ! PRINT STORED INFORMATION

/AXLAB,X, DEFLECTION (MM)

/AXLAB,Y, TOTAL LOAD (N)

/GRID,1

/XRANGE,0,35

/YRANGE,-500,1050

XVAR,5

PLVAR,4 ! PLOT LOAD WITH RESPECT TO -UY OF NODE 1

/NOERASE

!XVAR,6     !Chane

!PLVAR,4 ! PLOT LOAD WITH RESPECT TO -UY OF NODE 2  !Change

/ERASE

*DIM,LABEL,CHAR,2,2

*DIM,VALUE,,2,3

LABEL(1,1) = 'UY @A ','UY @B '

LABEL(1,2) = 'mm ','mm '

*VFILL,VALUE(1,1),DATA,-30,-26

*VFILL,VALUE(1,2),DATA,UY1,UY2

*VFILL,VALUE(1,3),DATA,ABS(UY1/30) ,ABS(UY2/26 )

FINISH

*END

SOLVIT

SAVE,TABLE_1+
```

Try to get table of resulting values

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post:
https://www.padtinc.com/2012/05/18/writing-text-files-with-vwrite/

The command you are looking for is called *VWRITE.

VM130 also gives an usage example. Formatting your numbers will take a bit of time.